# How do I use a HTML Form in Python?

Tags: python, html, forms

I have an HTML form with simple questions asking for an Username and Password. I want to use them in Python to insert into a database.
HTML Code:

```
     <form>
         <label for="user-name">Username:</label>
         <input type="text" name="username" id="user-name">
         <label for="user-pwd">Password:</label>
         <input type="password" name="user-password" id="user-pwd">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
```

How do I use this code in Python?

I tried using Flask, but I am inexperienced in it and did not know how to use it.

Comment: The best way would be to use a web framework such as flask.  There are many tutorials available on the web.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Flask, you should open up your terminal or command prompt to install Flask using pip using the code: pip install flask.

You can also follow the instructions from the below website, as it provides detailed step-by-step instructions:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-web-application-using-flask-in-python-3